# Angular Universal npm run serve:ssr returns "document is not defined"

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I've recently implemented Angular Universal for Angular 8. However running `npm run serve:ssr` returns the following:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at new CssKeyframesDriver (/Users/timfuhrmann/Documents/Entwicklung/norebro/node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js:4379:26)
    at instantiateSupportedAnimationDriver (/Users/timfuhrmann/Documents/Entwicklung/norebro/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js:412:88)
    at _callFactory (/Users/timfuhrmann/Documents/Entwicklung/norebro/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:21002:24)
    at _createProviderInstance (/Users/timfuhrmann/Documents/Entwicklung/norebro/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:20960:30)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (/Users/timfuhrmann/Documents/Entwicklung/norebro/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:20921:25)
    at _createClass (/Users/timfuhrmann/Documents/Entwicklung/norebro/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:20989:72)
    at _createProviderInstance (/Users/timfuhrmann/Documents/Entwicklung/norebro/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:20957:30)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (/Users/timfuhrmann/Documents/Entwicklung/norebro/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:20921:25)
    at _callFactory (/Users/timfuhrmann/Documents/Entwicklung/norebro/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:21008:71)
    at _createProviderInstance (/Users/timfuhrmann/Documents/Entwicklung/norebro/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:20960:30)
```

Does anybody know what that means?

Comment: This page has the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60636286/angular-9-ssr-build-serve-eror-error-referenceerror-document-is-not-defined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Client side code/keywords like `Document`, `Window`, `localstorage` etc will not present while running in the SSR/Universal mode of your angular application as your first page will be rendering on the server.

> window, document, localstorage, navigator, and other browser types - do not exist on the server - so using them, or any library that uses them (jQuery for example) will not work in the SSR mode.

So If in your code any such piece of code present then you need to wrap your client side code in `platformBrowser` like this -

```
import { ..., PLATFORM_ID, ... } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';


constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
){
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
       // Your client side code
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know I did. What exactly is client side code though? `*ngFor` etc.?

Comment: No code includes document, window, sessionStorage etc. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Do I solely have to edit the first component or every component?

Comment: IMO in every component, because every component must be included somewhere in some module and indirectly in the app.module or routing.

Comment: You mentioned navigator, what about routing?

Comment: not angular's routing, but yes navigatior as it is again doesn't exist on the server.

Comment: I have to inject `PLATFORM_ID` within the constructor? Right?

Comment: Is there a way find the location of the errors? Because I think I've edited everything I have to.

Comment: not sure, but you can enable sourcemap while build it will help you out.

Comment: What about host listeners and can libraries cause issues as well? Because I can't find further client side code and the error itself mentions "is not defined at..".

Comment: Got it, issue was caused by BrowserAnimationsModule, because as you mentioned, it includes client side code. Hence I removed the module - do you happen to know another bypass?

Answer (score 0):

this method is too hard to set up you need to browse all places where there is a navigator, window localstorage ... and make the modification.

It can be done upstream in server.ts, follow this link : 
 https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/general/framework-and-features/ssr-rendering.html